# Serve static files when using the Django WSGI app

Tags: django, wsgi, django-staticfiles

I am using the python-reload package. The readme gives this code to use it with django:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "hello.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    if 'livereload' in sys.argv:
        from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
        from livereload import Server
        application = get_wsgi_application()
        server = Server(application)

        # Add your watch
        # server.watch('path/to/file', 'your command')
        server.serve()
    else:
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

However Django doesn't serve staticfiles anymore. The runserver command still works, so I guess it's related to the wsgi app. How can I made django serve static files when using WSGI? Is it posible?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on [handling static files in development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)?

Comment: Ok, now it's done using urls.staticfiles_urlpatterns(), thanks